# Is it possible to find hive version using hive editor in Hue?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hue

I want to find my Hive version, I am using **Cloudera Hadoop** distribution,

> Is it possible to find hive version using hive editor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `select version();` or `set system:sun.java.command;` in Hue and look at the result

Comment: `set system:sun.java.command;` working for me

Comment: `select version();` worked for me (ver 3.1)